# Unexpected result with in_array() and multiple conditions in if expression

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an if expression where I want to check some items in an array and another variable. My original if expression was this:

```
if(!in_array($user->id, array($lsp->created_by_id, $lsp->approving_committee_pri_id, $lsp->approving_committee_sec_id)) or $user->level != 5)
{
    $error[] = 'You do not have permissions to modify this.';
}
```

However, I'm not getting the desired results. Essentially, if the user's id isn't in the array **or** the user's access level isn't equal to 5, then it should populate the `$error` array. Even when I modify the database so the user's id is in the array or his access level is equal to 5, it's still populating the `$error` array.

I've had to modify my code to this for it to work, which is kind of the opposite of my previous code:

```
if(in_array($user->id, array($lsp->created_by_id, $lsp->approving_committee_pri_id, $lsp->approving_committee_sec_id)) or $user->level == 5)
{
    //does nothing
}
else
{
    $error[] = 'You do not have permissions to modify this.';
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to do this in one line, but maybe I'm not understanding something correctly. I'm using PHP 5.4.14. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a || $b is not the opposite of !$a || !$b.

Try AND in your logic:

```
if(!in_array($user->id, array($lsp->created_by_id, $lsp->approving_committee_pri_id, $lsp->approving_committee_sec_id)) && $user->level != 5)
{
    $error[] = 'You do not have permissions to modify this.';
}
```

Meaning if neither of these things are true then the user doesn't have permission.

Comment: when im user level 4 and in the list? it shall error too according to the question

Comment: This is wrong bro. YOu allow me access if 1 condition is true, both conditions must be true "_if the user's id isn't in the array or the user's access level isn't equal to 5, [...] populate error_"

Comment: If level 4 and in the list then that would be `!$inList AND !$level5` which would be `true AND false`. This would pass.

Comment: I don't think an `and` would work though. I want either condition to be satisfied--the user is either in the array OR he has an access level = 5.

Comment: The askers working second example allows *either* condition to be true.

Comment: @Jeff Try my example. It will only fail if *both* conditions aren't met.

Comment: @Jim--yours works. I was just unable to wrap my head around the and being there. But now I understand _why_ it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use [`XOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

```
if(!in_array($user->id, array($lsp->created_by_id, $lsp->approving_committee_pri_id, $lsp->approving_committee_sec_id)) XOR $user->level != 5)
```

Meaning one or the other, but not both